# Nginx config for subdomains

Tags: nginx

My app structure is like so:

- /var/www/app/htdocs (the base app)
- /var/www/app/sites/example (where 'example' is a child site).

I want to set the root to `/var/www/app/htdocs` when www.mydomain.com or mydomain.com is requested.

I want to set the root to `/var/www/app/sites/example` when example.mydomain.com is requested.

How can I achieve this?

So far I've got:

```
server {
  listen 80;

  index index.php index.html index.htm;
  server_name ~^www\.(?P<sub>.+)\.mydomain\.com$ ~^(?P<sub>.+)\.mydomain\.com$;
  root /var/www/app/sites/$sub;

  location / {
  try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
  }

  location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
  }

  location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
  }
}
```

This will correctly display example.mydomain.com, but not www.mydomain.com, or mydomain.com. Any ideas? Also is there any way to whitelist subdomains?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new file in  /etc/nginx/sites-enabled 
name it as example.mydomain.com

edit the file, use following config :

```
    server {
        listen 80 ;
        server_name example.mydomain.com;
        root /var/www/app/sites/example;
  return         301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
        large_client_header_buffers 8 32k;
  if ($http_user_agent ~* Googlebot) {  
    return 403; 
  }




    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

        location ~ \.php$ {
                include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
        }

        location ~ /\.ht {
                deny all;
        }
}
```

use nginx -t reload to check the config file
make an entry in your Domain name service provider.